# ValidationSummary stays visible after errors are corrected?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, validation

I have a ValidationSummary that works pretty well, although it doesn't go away after the last of the form errors are rectified.

I'm not sure if this is default behavior or a bug. It seems more towards the latter, since they don't go away after my form has been submitted.

The only thing I suspect might be impacting the functionality is that the form is created through `Ajax.BeginForm()`.

Even still, shouldn't the ValidationSummary disappear **right** as I hit the submit button?

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: Seems like it may be related to AJAX, but hard to tell without seeing code...

Comment: You have not added any code so its hard to understand the problem thats why i suggest you to use jQuery Unobtrusive Validation library, it is developed by Microsoft and is included in the ASP.NET MVC framework. here is the [example to use it](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make it hide on form submit in your javascript. If you inspect element on your validation summary, you'll notice it changes styles from `.validation-summary-valid` to `.validation-summary-errors` if there are any errors. So this makes it easy to hide.

e.g.

```
$('#formName').submit(function() {
    if ($(this).valid()) { // checks form is valid.
        $('.validation-summary-errors').hide(); // hides it
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of something I've used prior, hopefully it helps anyone who finds this. I kinda disagree with the accepted answer as it breaks the usability of the summary later.

```
$("form#AJAX_FormA").on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).validate();
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        $('.validation-summary-errors ul li').attr("style", "display:none"); //Hide
        $('.validation-summary-errors').removeClass("validation-summary-errors").addClass("validation-summary-valid");
        ajaxGenerateList($(this).serialize());
    }
});
```